# This question is related to graph. Can anybody give me some hint?

Tags: graph-theory

In this question, we consider undirected graphs. The diameter 
of a graph is defined as the maximum distance between any pair of nodes in the 
graph. The average distance in a graph is the average distance over all pairs of 
nodes in the graph. Describe how you could construct a graph in which the 
diameter exceeds the average distance by as large a factor as you’d like. (That is, 
for every number c, can you produce a graph in which the diameter is more than c 
times as large as the average distance?)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't thought this through but see what you can do with it.

To keep the average distance down you want lots of vertices close together.  To make the diameter large you want *some* vertices a long way apart.

So try taking the complete graph on $n$ vertices (lots of distances equal $1$) and then attach to one vertex a long "tail" of length $m$.  If you juggle the values of $n$ and $m$ you might be able to make it work.